# Does SwiftUI AWS Face Liveness requires NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription purpose string?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, aws-amplify

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/swift/connected-components/liveness

Here is the package dependencies used for my project

[image: Here is the package dependencies used for my project]

Here is the error i got when i try to upload my app to testflight

[image: Here is the error i got when i try to upload my app to testflight]

for now i have added NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription just for the sake of allowing my app to be uploaded to testflight [image: Here is the description that i added even tho my app is not using the speech API]

And i need to emphasize again, my app does not use any speech recognition API

Question:

1. Do i really need to specify NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription in this case? And if yes, what description should i write?

**[INFO].[Edited on 20231224]**
**[11:23 pm, Sunday, 24 December 2023, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)]**
**[Purpose] Added search result image for 'AWSPredictionsPlugin' from 'Amplify' plugin**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that list of packages, the [Amplify](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift) repo contains a Predictions plugin that accesses iOS's Speech methods as backups for when AWS services are unreachable:

> On iOS, we leverage Apple’s Core ML Vision Framework and Natural Language Framework to improve accuracy as well as support cases where your device is unable to reach AWS Services. For more information, see each individual use case.

[source](https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/build-a-backend/more-features/predictions/set-up-predictions/)

While you have to `import AWSPredictionsPlugin` to use these functions in your own code, it's possible that the whole package gets added to your binary – and so your app may appear to Apple's analysis tools to contain `NSSpeechRecognition`-based code.

Comment: after some reading on the 'source' that you have attached, it seems like 'Amplify' does default include 'AWSPredictionsPlugin' (Image Added). May i know, based on your experience, what description should i write for 'NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription' ? thanks in advance

Comment: I’d be honest. “This app uses a third party library that includes several plugins, including speech recognition, that aren’t used in this app.”